# Is there application client for ElasticSeach 6.4.3 (similar to DBvear)

Tags: elasticsearch, application-client

I tried to see my node data from application client (like DBvear), but I didn't found information about that. someone found way to connect DBvear to this version or to see the data by similar application?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is GUI for Elasticsearch.

Typically the industry calls the elasticsearch stack as `ELK` stack and I believe what you are looking for is the `K` part of it which is [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/kibana).

I'm not sure if you are asking for SQL feature but if you are thinking to make use of the SQL feature you can check the [Elasticsearch SQL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-sql.html) plugin.

Other widely used client application for elasticsearch is [Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/elasticsearch/). There are others available too(I think Splunk, Graylog, Loggly) but I believe Kibana and Grafana are the best bet.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Actually no, I using elastic search as a Database in different deployments and I don't want to maintenance Kibana instance (i prefer to see all the data in tool like DBvear)